# What is the "http"/IIS capacity of an EC2 micro instance?

Tags: windows, iis, web-applications, amazon-ec2

I want to separate the current high cpu medium instance that I have into high cpu + micro instance in order to take in more http traffic. Does anyone know how many simultaneous connections can a micro instance take in? The initial idea is to separate the db and host it from sql azure but due to some old stored procedures, I'm opting to stay on a pure ec2 setup. The reason is because the current instance already takes in 100% cpu at times.

Answer (score -1):

This question is quite old so presumably you've made the decision on your own, but just for posterity:

The capacity of any server will vary WIDELY depending on what you're using it for.  It would be silly to even speculate on a value.  If each HTTP request requires lots of server processing, combing through database results, repackaging media from other servers, you could quickly overload a Micro.  However, if all you're doing is basic web serving, you could probably do alright for a while.

The only way to answer a question like this is to set up the micro instance and test it yourself.  Set up your development workstation to flood it with requests, and then keep an eye on the response time and CPU usage in AWS CloudWatch to see if the behavior you get is acceptable to you.

(As a side note, there are also differences in network I/O between the various EC2 sizes, so if performance under heavy load seems bad but the CPU isn't working hard, it may be I/O bound.)